# I got TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON error in twilio joining to channel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, twilio

Reading this docs https://www.twilio.com/blog/implementing-programmable-chat-php-laravel-vue-js
I try to add in my Laravel 8 / jQuery 3.5.1 / vue 2.6 / Bootstrap 4.5
chat when logged user select another user I run axios request to check if channel was
created priorly(or create a new channel). On client part

```
connectClientWithUsername(){
    this.tc.username = this.loggedUser.name

    let vm = this;
    axios.post('/admin/team-chat/check_channel', {
        sender_id : vm.loggedUser.id,
        receiver_id : vm.selectedTeamUser.id
    })
        .then(({data}) => {
            console.log('check_channel data::')
            console.log(data)
            
            vm.newChartCreated= data.newChartCreated // Flag if new chat was created
            vm.currentChatChannelName= data.currentChatChannelName // Name of requested channel
            vm.fetchAccessToken(vm.tc.username, vm.connectMessagingClient);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
            popupAlert('Team Chat', error.response.data.message, 'warn')
            vm.is_page_loaded = true
        })
},

fetchAccessToken(username, handler) {
    let vm = this;
    axios.post('/token', {
        identity: this.tc.username,
        device: 'browser'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            handler(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
},
```

And on server part in app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TeamChatController.php:

```
public function check_channel(Request $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $chatName= "public_oo_team_chat_" . $requestData['sender_id'] . '_' . $requestData['receiver_id'];
    $newChartCreated = false;
    $chatChannel = null;
    try {
        $channel = $this->twilio->chat->v2->services(config('app.TWILIO_SERVICE_SID'))
                                          ->channels($chatName)
                                          ->fetch();

    } catch(RestException $e) {
        $channel = $this->twilio->chat->v2->services(config('app.TWILIO_SERVICE_SID'))
            ->channels->create([
                'uniqueName'    => $chatName,
                'friendlyName'  => $chatName,
                'type'          => 'public'  // New channel was created
            ]);
        if($channel->sid) {
            $chatChannel= new ChatChannel(); // Ref to newly created channel was saved in db
            $chatChannel->sender_id= $requestData['sender_id'];
            $chatChannel->receiver_id= $requestData['receiver_id'];
            $chatChannel->channel_name= $chatName;
            $chatChannel->last_chat_at= Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
            $chatChannel->save();
        }
        $newChartCreated= true;

    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => '',
        'chatChannel' => $chatChannel,
        'newChartCreated' => $newChartCreated, // return name of current Channel
        'currentChatChannelName' => $chatName], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
} // check_channel


public function getToken(Request $request)
{
    $this->identity = $request->identity;
    $token = new AccessToken(
        $this->twilio_account_sid,
        $this->twilio_api_key,
        $this->twilio_api_secret,
        3600,
        $this->identity
    );
    // Create Chat grant
    $chat_grant = new ChatGrant();
    $chat_grant->setServiceSid($this->service_sid);

    // Add grant to token
    $token->addGrant($chat_grant);
    // render token to string
    echo $token->toJWT();
}
```

and I when I get token from server I create client and try to conect to channel

```
    connectMessagingClient(token) {  // connects the user to the Twilio Chat client.
        // Initialize the Chat messaging client
        let vm = this;

        this.tc.accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(token);

        new Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token).then(function(client) {
            vm.tc.messagingClient = client;
            vm.updateConnectedUI();
            vm.connectToActiveChannel(client) // I try to connect to channel I need

            // vm.tc.messagingClient.on('channelAdded', _.throttle(vm.loadChannelList));
            // vm.tc.messagingClient.on('channelRemoved', _.throttle(vm.loadChannelList));
            // vm.tc.messagingClient.on('tokenExpired', vm.refreshToken);
        });
    },

    connectToActiveChannel(messagingClient) {
        let vm = this

        // Get all public channels
        messagingClient.getPublicChannelDescriptors().then(function(channels) {
            for (let i = 0; i < channels.items.length; i++) {
                const channel = channels.items[i];
            }
            vm.tc.channelArray = channels.items;

            vm.tc.channelArray.forEach(vm.addChannel); // Check for selected channel
        });

    },

    addChannel(channel){
        console.log('addChannel channel::')
        console.log(typeof channel)
        if (channel.uniqueName === this.currentChatChannelName) {
            this.tc.generalChannel = channel;
            console.log('FOUND  this.tc.generalChannel!!!')
            console.log( this.tc.generalChannel )
            return this.joinChannel(channel);
        }
    },

    joinChannel(_channel) { // the member joins the channel (general or a personally created channel)
        console.log(" joinChannel   _channel");
        console.log(_channel);
        let vm = this;
        return _channel.join()
            .then(function(joinedChannel) {
                console.log('Joined channel ' + joinedChannel.friendlyName);
                vm.updateChannelUI(_channel);
                vm.tc.currentChannel = _channel;
                vm.loadMessages();
                return joinedChannel;
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                alert("Couldn't join channel " + _channel.friendlyName + ' because ' + err);
            });
    },
```

and in joinChannel I got error :

```
vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'l'
    |     property '_fsm' -> object with constructor 'o'
    --- property 'context' closes the circle"
```

on line:

```
return _channel.join()
```

I see in the browser's console :

https://prnt.sc/wekctp
and
https://prnt.sc/wekspu

Looks like there is an error in my flow, but it seems to me that I passwed valid object to line :

```
_channel.join
```

Why error and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this code:

```js
    connectToActiveChannel(messagingClient) {
        let vm = this

        // Get all public channels
        messagingClient.getPublicChannelDescriptors().then(function(channels) {
            for (let i = 0; i < channels.items.length; i++) {
                const channel = channels.items[i];
            }
            vm.tc.channelArray = channels.items;

            vm.tc.channelArray.forEach(vm.addChannel); // Check for selected channel
        });

    }
```

This line doesn't seem to do anything (it iterates over the list of channel descriptors, creating a new `channel` const for each of them, but then immediately discarding it.

Then, you set the `vm.tc.channelArray` to the list of channel descriptors and call `vm.addChannel` for each of the descriptors.

Note here that `getPublicChannelDescriptors()` returns a list of [`ChannelDescriptor` objects](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.1.0/docs/ChannelDescriptor.html). `ChannelDescriptor`s cannot be joined and contain a snapshot of data about a channel at the time it was requested.

To join a channel, you would need to first call [`getChannel()` on the channel descriptor](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.1.0/docs/ChannelDescriptor.html#getChannel__anchor) first, then perform the rest of your code.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! What about "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error ? - looks like it is rendered by  console.log when I debug results... Very annoying... Maybe some wrapper messages ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing that as I don't have the app to hand and can't dig through the backtrace. It does seem to be coming from Vue trying to render something (an error?) rather than your logging though. If you get the channel with `getChannel` and then try to join the channel object instead of the descriptor, does it all go away?